# Easiest way to make DB records as array keys

Tags: php, mysql

What is the easiest and fastest way to get or manipulate the MySQL result with id values as keys in PHP? I know we can simply loop through the entire result set and so on. But what is the fastest and also the simplest way of doing this?

That is to convert,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_name] => user1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3        
            [user_name] => user3
        )

)
```

to this.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_name] => user1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3        
            [user_name] => user3
        )

)
```

This question may face some downvotes. But still, i think any answer on this would be helpfull to many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$new_array = array_column($old_array, NULL, 'id');
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Set the second parameter to NULL to keep the id in the result

Comment: No, then the `key` will be dropped and array will be zero indexed

Comment: He wants `id` to be used as key for the new array

Comment: Oops yes thats right, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

So construct the array by using the id as key.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = db_dummy_fetch_method($res)) {
    $result[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```